# Declaration or Definition

Tags: c++

Is this, *line of code that is presented below and under this sentence*, considered a declaration or definition?

```
extern const int &ri;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a declaration- the "extern" means that it lives somewhere else.

Comment: The presence of `extern` alone does not necessarily mean that this is not a definition. For example, `extern const int &ri = 42;` *is* a definition. It is not correct to say that "`extern` means that it lives somewhere else". `extern` means that the name has *external linkage*. It doesn't say anything about where the entity behind the name lives. It could live here or elsewhere, depending on other details of the declaration (like presence of an initializer, for example).

Comment: @AndreyT he says *the* "extern". I take it he refers to this specific use of that token. The `extern` in this case is necessary for that declaration to be not a definition. +1 for a correct, if subtle, answer.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Well, OK. Maybe I missed that nuance. Interpret my comment as just an additional sidenote. Also, I didn't downvote . (Although once can probably argue that it is not the *presence* of `extern`, but rather the *absence* of an initializer that makes it a non-defining declaration.)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *declaration* and *definition* are not mutually exclusive concepts. Every definition is a declaration at the same time (with few exceptions). Which means that the proper way to ask the question would be: "Is this a defining declaration or a non-defining declaration?".

Note that I'm not saying that the question the way it is now is meaningless. The question is fine, because everybody understands what is really meant by it. I just wanted to say this as an introductory note.

Secondly, what you have here is a non-defining declaration, meaning that this declaration is not a definition (a reference or object declaration with `extern` specifier but without an initializer is not a definition).

In case of

```
extern const int &ri = 5;
```

we'd also have a *declaration*, but this would be a *defining* declaration (i.e. a declaration that happens to be a definition).

Comment: what would happen if there were two translation units containing `extern const int &ri = 5;`?

Comment: @David Heffernan: In C++ that would be a violation of ODR - more than one definition of the same entity with external linkage. In C this is also an error of the same kind. However, in C allowing multiple identical definitions has always been a popular extension (it is even mentioned in C standard). I wouldn't be surprised to see some C++ compilers implement that extension as well, although C++ compilers are usually more strict in this regard.

Comment: @AndreyT: Sorry for making this comment here, but it seems you didn't get the notification from the chat: You didn't have to delete your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322685/why-is-it-forbidden-to-open-multiple-namespaces-at-a-stretch/6322697#6322697), I edited the question and the original one didn't mention if opening a new namespace or extending an existing one was meant.

Comment: @Xeo: I thought that the comment "open nested namespace bar in foo and extend it" in the original question implies extension of an existing namespace.

Comment: @AndreyT: I made that comment, the original question didn't hint at what was meant.

Answer (score 3):

C++03, §3.1, ¶2:

> A declaration is a definition unless ... it contains the extern specifier or a linkage- specification and neither an initializer nor a function-body ...

So, `extern const int &ri;`, which contains the `extern` specifier and not an initializer is a declaration but not a definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
extern const int &ri;
```

Its a *declaration* ONLY with no definition, which indicates that the variable is *defined* elsewhere.

Such code is *usually* found in `.h` file, and its definition is found in `.cpp` file. This approach is used to avoid multiple-redefinition error if you include the header file in multiple files. Something like this:

```
//lib.h
extern Type object; //declaration Only;

//lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"
Type object = /*some initialization - optional*/; //definition

//A.cpp
#include "lib.h"
Type oA = object;

//B.cpp
#include "lib.h"
Type oB = object;
```

---

The usage of `const`at namespace level makes the variable being declared or defined to have internal-linkage, it becomes like an *immutable* `static` variable, which exists only in its own translation unit.

`extern const` makes the variable to have external-linkage, at the same time, the  variable is constant.

```
namespace N
{
    const int i = 10;         //i has internal linkage
    extern const int j = 10;  //j has external linkage
}
```

In this case, `extern` is used to make the variable to have external-linkage!

§3.5/3 [basic.link]:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.5)
>   has **internal linkage** if it is the name
>   of
>   — an object, reference, function or
>   function template that is explicitly
>   declared static or,
>   — an object or
>   reference that is **explicitly declared
>   const and neither explicitly declared
>   extern nor previously declared to have
>   external linkage**; or
>   — a data member
>   of an anonymous union.

Comment: Note that `const` in this original example is a "second-level" `const`, which applies to the object being referred by reference. It doesn't apply to the reference itself (in fact, it is illegal to even try that). That means that even though what you are saying is correct, in the original example that `extern` has nothing to do with that `const`. That reference declaration would have external linkage even without `extern`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from anything else, it is almost certainly a misuse of a reference. References are intended to be used as function parameters and and return values. THe fact that you can create "reference variables" (I don't know how else to describe them) seems to have been an accident of the C++ grammar. Yes, you can do tricks with them, but no, you shouldn't.

Bottom line - if you have a reference that isn't a parameter or a return value, you are probably doing something wrong. Unless you really, really know what you are doing, in which case you wouldn't be asking about it here, would you?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. What about reference data members? I use them alot.

Comment: Butterworth: Er... I don't see anything wrong with using a local reference variable with run-time binding, as in `SomeType &r = <some condition> ? <lvalue1> : <lvalue2>;` (and then proceed working with `r`). It is a widely used and very useful technique, unless you are trying to say that one has to use *pointers* for that purpose.

Comment: @Andrey `SomeType &r = <some condition> ? <lvalue1> : <lvalue2>;` Well, I suppose I never write that kind of code. A real example might clarify why one would.

Comment: Butterworth: It is like asking me come come up with an example of using `if` statement... I'd have hard time doing that because the language feature is so *generic* that trying to make a *specific* example for it feels absolutely pointless. Let's say I have a piece of code that works with either lvalue `a` or lvalue `b` (depending on some condition). So, that's how I would write it: create a run-time alias `r` for `a` or `b` (depending on the condition) and then work with `r`. How is that for an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using `extern` would indicate that the object is not defined here, but somewhere else.