# Why is it forbidden to open multiple namespaces at a stretch?

Tags: c++, namespaces, standards, nested, language-lawyer

It's possible to do `using namespace foo::bar;` (i.e., using the inner namespace without using the outer namespace first / at all), why does the standard forbid to do the following?

```
namespace foo::bar {
  // open nested namespace bar in foo and extend it...
}
```

I'm not looking for a workaround, just a possible rational on why this isn't allowed.

Comment: Really not sure why this question has been downvoted.

Comment: Voting down / to close perfectly valid questions? A rant isn't a reason to downvote, really. Just edit it out.

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm guessing "the C++ standard is flawed with many aberrations..." can tick people off.

Comment: @Warren: Did you mean to directly open a new namespace or to reopen an already declared namespace and extend it?

Comment: It is forbidden because there is no syntax that allows it ;)

Comment: Personally I think it was an oversight. I see no problems with allowing that syntactic form.

Comment: @Xeo: Both, but I can't see why it would make a difference.

Comment: @Martin: Indeed, I used to work on a "almost-standard-compliant" static analyzer that was extended to provide such a syntax and rewrite it correctly. AFAIK, no unsolvable ambiguity.

Comment: @Warren: It makes a difference. As a now deleted answer from @AndreyT says: "As a general rule, everywhere in C++ language qualified names, like `A::B` are used to refer to previously declared entities. You can't introduce new entities with qualified names.". So, declaring a new namespace would be inconsistent.

Comment: @Xeo: Ok. I guess that's what @AshleysBrain is trying to say in his answer. That's too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure "forbidden" is the right word - maybe it was just an oversight.  It's a fairly small nice-to-have which isn't really a big deal.

You could also take the point of view that the namespace `foo` isn't created yet when you write `foo::bar`, so allowing that syntax makes it look like `foo` was already created when it was not.

You could also go further and request the ability to write `class Foo::MyClass {...` to define `MyClass` in namespace `Foo`, and the same for functions, variables, etc.  But is this feature really necessary and solving any particular pressing problem?

Comment: If you consider the namespace feature as one feature in the whole C++ language, then it's not a big deal. However, if you just take the namespace feature itself, and compare it to how it works in other languages (such as C#), then it really sucks. Also, I can't think of any ambiguity caused by recursively creating missing namespaces in compound namespace expressions, addressing your second paragraph.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overreacting by saying it "really sucks"?  It hardly makes namespaces useless or fundamentally inferior to any other system.  It's just a minor oversight IMO.

Comment: If you forward-declare `class MyClass;` in `namespace Foo {...}`, you can say `class Foo::MyClass {...};` (at least with GCC).

Comment: Yeah, the "really" in "really sucks" is probably too strong. Still, C++ developers seem to hate names nested more than 3 levels (per the comments to DeadMG's answer), and I can't help but think it's related to this issue. For instance, in C++ you wouldn't like to have Java-like naming conventions for your namespaces (`org::apache::commons::collections::BidiMap`, anyone?), and it's kinda weird that the _syntax_ is the main blocker for such names.

Comment: The syntax doesn't block it, see DeadMG's answer.  Also, I guess most of the time something comes between the namespace declarations, so you wouldn't even use the foo::bar syntax.  It's such a tiny tiny thing, has it really affected anything and does it even deserve to say it "sucks"?  I say not...!

Answer (score 0):

Why make compilers implement it when you could just do

```
namespace foo { namespace bar {

}}
```

Comment: Why make compilers implement *any* feature when the users can emulate it themselves? Always the same reason: to reduce the users’ work.

Comment: Well, that's not really an answer, no? The OP not explicitly asks for workarounds but a possible reasoning. Also, consider nestings > 3. I know, that such abominations shouldn't be done, but they're out there in the wild. :/

Comment: @Konrad: The compiler saves the user *significant* work. Not ten characters. @Xeo: Not making people implement it is a perfectly valid reason to not Standardize it- look at `export`.

Comment: @DeadMG: I think you already had a similar argument on lambdas / function local closures. Sure, typing them up isn't hard and barely spans 5 lines (with a macro not even 3), but they were implemented as a language feature anyways.

Comment: @DeadMG I find it pretty significant. C++ has such an amount of syntactical clutter that I spend a good part of my programming in C++ actually *typing*. No modern language should require this. In particular, having to open nested namespace declarations is *really annoying*. If I could just write `namespace x::y::z` this would be quite a time-saver.

Comment: I'm not convinced with this answer. It doesn't attempt to rationalize the rule laid down by the Standard, against the *seem-to-be-better* alternative asked by the OP.

Comment: @Xeo: Lambdas save the user vastly more than this would do- the overhead per parameter is quite considerable, and there are other advantages like the code being written-in-place, to the point where nobody ever did it before lambdas. This, however, is perfectly doable this way. @Konrad: There are other places which require way more syntactic overhead than opening more than one namespace at once.

Comment: DeadMG, I can't agree with your argument that the compiler _only_ saves significant work to the user. This is just backwards. From C++03 to C++11, we gained the ability to _eliminate the single space character_ between nested template arguments like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Who's going to love a language that does the bare minimum to help you? It's not like this feature would get in the way of advanced users either.